# Problem with jQuery Ajax in a Django project

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django, ajax

I'm working on a small project with Django, and there is a section that needs to do with Ajax jQuery.

Unfortunately, I don't know about JavaScript, and it's libraries yet. I will appreciate it if you help me.

I want to make Follow and Unfollow buttons.

But there is a problem: I did it with VAR to make a variable, but it didn't recognize and told me I need to use LET.

Also, I have defined URL and some, etc., which it doesn't recognize too.

Add to that; I have two variable, which has two different names but one path, but It seems it's wrong too.

The JavaScript code:

```js
$('#following-btn').click(function() {
    let user_id = $('#following-btn').attr('data-id')
    let follow = $('#following-btn').text();

    if (follow === 'follow') {
        let url = '/account/follow/'
        let btn_text = 'unfollow'
        let btn_class = 'btn btn-warning text-center mx-auto'
    } else {
        let url = '/account/unfollow/'
        let btn_text = 'follow'
        let btn_class = 'btn btn-primary text-center mx-auto'
    }

    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method:'POST',
            data:{'user.id':user_id,},
            success:function (data) {
                if (data['status'] === 'ok'){
                    $('#following-btn').text(btn_text)
                    $('#following-btn').attr({class: btn_class})
                }
            }
        }
    )
})
```

The view and path:

```py
{% if request.user.id != user.id and not is_following %}
    <button id="following-btn" data-id="{{ user.id }}" style="display: block" class="btn btn-primary text-center mx-auto"> Follow</button>
    {% elif request.user.id != user.id and is_following %}
    <button id="following-btn" data-id="{{ user.id }}" style="display: block" class="btn btn-warning text-center mx-auto"> Unfollow</button>
    {% endif %}
```

The problem:

[image]

Comment: There are several issues I have spotted: 
 - You are getting the text from the button with the id 'following-btn'. This text is either ' Follow' or ' Unfollow' but never 'follow' as you are checking for it. 
 - You are missing the semicolons after many of your statements. Starting with the first one. Make sure to end each statement with a semicolon. 
 - You are defining the variables multiple times: I would suggest a default case and only reassign the variables when it's not your default case.

Comment: @AnnaM: Thank you, Anna, for your response. I watched this code in a video and in that instead LET, used VAR and ... and finally worked for him. As I said before, I don't know anything about JQuery, and I think the format of code is right here, but because JavaScript update, I need to change some of them if you know how I will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A few things that I think need to change here;

Firstly, I think you are going to need to provide your CSRFToken in your AJAX request to Django to validate the input. I have this to do this with my setups.

Easiest way to acheive this is to use the `cookie.js` library as below:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/js.cookie.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    let csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
</script>
```

The library is available here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/js-cookie

Secondly, as Anna mentioned, you are not using the attributes of the button quite right and in my opinion effectively. I would set the value of the button to the current following state, ensure it is uppercase to avoid case-sensitivity and also use `$(this)` to avoid re-querying the DOM.

**HTML**

```
{% if request.user.id != user.id and not is_following %}
    <button id="following-btn" data-id="{{ user.id }}" style="display: block" class="btn btn-primary text-center mx-auto" value="follow"> Follow</button>
    {% elif request.user.id != user.id and is_following %}
    <button id="following-btn" data-id="{{ user.id }}" style="display: block" class="btn btn-warning text-center mx-auto" value="unfollow"> Unfollow</button>
    {% endif %}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#following-btn').click(function() {
    let user_id = $(this).attr('data-id');  // Use $(this) to avoid re-querying the DOM
    let follow = $(this).value().toUpperCase(); // Lets avoid case-sensitivity by making everything uppercase for comparison
    
    var url = '/account/follow/';
    var btn_text = 'unfollow';
    var btn_class = 'btn btn-warning text-center mx-auto';

    if (follow === 'UNFOLLOW') {
        url = '/account/unfollow/';
        btn_text = 'follow';
        btn_class = 'btn btn-primary text-center mx-auto';
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method:'POST',
        data:{'user.id':user_id,},
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data['status'] === 'ok'){
                $(this).text(btn_text);
                $(this).attr({class: btn_class});
            }
        }
    });
});
```